# Validation in beforeFind on Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a group messaging feature in an app I'm working on, and for that I have a Message class and Group class.
The "Group" class contains an array of users pointers, and the "Message" class contains a pointer to a Group.
What I want is to add a method in the Message beforeFind that checks if the loggedIn users are allowed to fetch the messages they're requesting based on their availability in the Group, this seems to be straight forward in the beforeFind method, but when I try to query the "Group" class in the Message's beforeFind, it's getting ignored and the fetching of messages is proceeding, how can this be solved?

I know I can use ACL on Message class, but this is a hassle when a new user is added or removed from the Group, I'll have to go through the whole messages and modify the ACL so this is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Also ACLs can use a Role based permission, so instead of modifying the ACL of every Message object you can create a Role for each group, which also controls permissions for the Group object.  Or, you could use something like Twilio Chat. Cheap and effective.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I'll post the beforeFind code once I'm home, even though it's just a simple query to the group class that returns success or error. 

I know I can use Role based permission, but I don't think role based permissions are made for that, I read somewhere that once the number of roles exceeds a certain number you start facing performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

A better design would be to have the group unique role, then when users join the group, they get added to the group role, and when they leave the group, they get removed from the group role. Then for all messages in the group, set the ACL to be the group's role.